# Сортировка по двум элементам

Tags: c++

```
struct compareNodesXy
{

        bool operator()(Node6&a,Node6&b){
            return a.x == b.y && a.y==b.x;

    }
}sortNodesxy;
sort(takeNode.begin(), takeNode.end(), sortNodesxy);
```

Что я делаю не так , так как сортировка не работает
У меня список точек

```
1 0 
2 3
2 5
0 5
0 1
3 2
10 5
5 2
```

Мне нужно чтобы оно стало так

```
0 1
1 0
2 5
5 2
итд
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Очевидно, нужно использовать оператор неравенства, а не равенства.

Comment: А какой принцип сортировки? Почему 1 0 меньше 0 1, но при этом 2 5 меньше 5 2?..

Comment: Да, я так написал , но принцип следующий,надо чтобы он поставил все точки по порядку .. Мне неважно 1 0 или 0 1 , но нужно чтобы они стояли в ряд 0 1 1 0

Comment: Тогда компоратор будет к примеру  `min(a.x, a.y) < min (b.x, b.y) || min(a.x, a.y) == min (b.x, b.y)  && max(a.x, a.y) < max(b.x, b.y) `

Comment: павел , спасибо тебе большое! Могу поставить плюс , если оформишь как ответ

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать примерно такой компаратор:

```
min(a.x, a.y) < min (b.x, b.y) || min(a.x, a.y) == min (b.x, b.y) && max(a.x, a.y) < max(b.x, b.y)
```

Идея - сортировать по возрастанию меньше координаты, потом большей. Тогда пары {a,b}{b,a} будут гарантированно стоять рядом. ( если все точки уникальны).